# Is there any way to use Client Certificates with ASP.NET 5?

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, client-certificates

We are developing an ASP.NET 5 project and one of the requirements is that user authentication is done through client certificates via browser, but I can't make this work.

Using `web.config` and IIS the certificate is requested properly with this configuration:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
    <authentication>
      <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But the client certificate does not arrive to the web application, as I understand it should be in `context.Connection.ClientCertificate` property, where `context` is the current `HttpContext`.

I suspect that `httpPlatformHandler` that tunnels IIS to Kestrel is ignoring https and this may be implemented in the future.

I have made some tests with an OWIN site (not DNX) and a custom `AuthenticationHandler` that gets the X509 client certificate and works properly under IIS.

Comment: Which beta version are you using?

Comment: I tried with beta8 and development releases but I think that the problem is with `httpPlatformHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there has been some work done on this and a pull request and merge was done implementing this. So... hopefully we'll see it in a updated release of Kestrel.

See here: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/pull/385

Answer (score 1):

As I can read in the [Change to IIS hosting model](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69) announcement:

> - The HttpPlatformHandler currently does not forward client certs (this will be a future enhancement)

So, it seems that is not possible right now and [`httpPlaformHandler`](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler) must be fixed.